# How to set proxy with authorization to Spring Webflux WebClient (ReactorClientHttpConnector)?

Tags: spring-webflux

I´m using Spring WebClient into a library to consume an API, but I need to setup a proxy with authentication to do the call behind a proxy server.

How can I do this?

```java
String myUrl = "https://api.mycompany.com/api/my-resource";

WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();

String result = webClient.get().uri(myUrl)
          .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
          .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_CHARSET, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
          .header(HttpHeaders.HOST, "mycompany.com")
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(String.class)
          .block();

// TODO: How to set the proxy into WebClient?

// TODO: how to set the proxy authorization?
```

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to use the 'clientConnector' to set proxy settings and then add a proxy authorization into headers.

Solution/example:

```java
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;
import reactor.netty.transport.ProxyProvider;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;

...


String myUrl = "https://api.mycompany.com/api/my-resource";

// With Proxy
String proxyHost = "proxy-address";
Integer proxyPort = 1234;
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).address(new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)));
ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
builder.clientConnector(connector);
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build();


// Set Proxy Authorization on Request
String authorizationToken = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(("my-username" + ":" + "my-password").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

String result = webClient.get().uri(myUrl)
          .header(HttpHeaders.PROXY_AUTHORIZATION,"Basic " + authorizationToken)
          .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
          .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_CHARSET, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
          .header(HttpHeaders.HOST, "mycompany.com")
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(String.class)
          .block();
```

build.gradle

```
    compile "io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:1.0.9"
    compile "io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:1.0.9"
```